# NoMethodError (undefined method `keys' for true:TrueClass): Jquery Datatable Ruby on rails 5.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

i am facing this problem and i tried to test only to get results from User model.
    NoMethodError (undefined method `keys' for true:TrueClass):
    app/controllers/handymen_controller.rb:12:in`block (2 levels) in index'
    app/controllers/handymen_controller.rb:9:in `index'

this is the controller

```
def index
#@handymen = Handyman.search(params[:profession])
  line 9  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
 line 12     format.json {render json: HandymanDatatable.new(view_context)}
end
  end
```

this is the datatable

```
class HandymanDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base

  def view_columns
#  list of the model(s) columns mapped to the data we need to present
# Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
# or in aliased_join_table.column_name format
@view_columns ||= {
   id: { source: "User.id", cond: :like, searchable: true, orderable: true},
   first_name: { source: "User.first_name"},
}
    Rails.logger.debug("view_columns 123")
```

end

```
  def data
records.map do |record|
  {
    id: record.id,
    first_name: record.first_name,
    DT_RowId:   record.id,
  }
    end
  end


  def get_raw_records

    Rails.logger.debug("this is the dataTable 123")
    byebug
    User.where(id: 7)
```

end

```
end
```

this is the javascript file for Datatable

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#handymen-datatable').dataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": $('#handymen-datatable').data('source'),
"pagingType": "full_numbers",
"columns": [
  {"data": "id"},
  {"data": "first_name"}
]
// pagingType is optional, if you want full pagination controls.
// Check dataTables documentation to learn more about
// available options.
```

});
});

this is the model

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  #  :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable

  belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true

  def handyman?
profile_type == "Handyman"
```

end
end

Comment: Can you show us where view_context is being defined?

Comment: @Rigo [view_context](https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing parameters along with the view_context.

`format.json { render json: HandymanDatatable.new(params, view_context: view_context) }`

instead of

`format.json { render json: HandymanDatatable.new(view_context) }`

Answer (score 0):

guys thank you for cooperation i found the answer to the problem.
it's within view_columns method in the datatable.
when i removed Rails.logger.debug the code is worked .
but i really don't understand why this is happening if someone can explain to me.

Comment: I know this is an older comment, but in case anyone is still looking, this is an easy mistake to make.  Because rails implicitly returns the last line of the method, when you add a debugger at the end, then all it returns is the debugger.  Without that, it returns `@view_columns`.  If you want to put a debugger after `@view_columns = ....`, then you need to also put `@view_columns` on the last line, so that it is returned.